# Why are chairs badly designed?

Tags: user-expectation, design

Why are chairs designed the way they are, when the sitting position of a chair isn't natural or healthy for humans?

A squatting position is a lot more natural, and sitting on a chair for hours can actually harm our spine, hips and make us less flexible.

**Resources:**

- [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOJLx4Du3vU) explains how the shape of our spine naturally let's us sit in a squatting position, and how the shape of our spine has shifted since by the usage of chairs, causing back pain and other injuries that countries which use chairs a lot less don't have, or in less quantity.
- [This article](http://www.core77.com/posts/37902/Theory-that-American-Lifestyle-has-Changed-the-Shape-of-our-Spines) also talks about how the shape of our spine changed due to what they call the "american lifestyle".
- If that isn't enough, [here is another](http://besynchro.com/blogs/blog/10612681-your-chair-is-killing-you-time-to-start-squatting) article which explains how this works.

Really, there is a lot to find about why it is bad for you. It obviously doesn't happen overnight though.

Comment: can you point to any research backing that claim up?

Comment: [You can see here how exceptionally unnatural sitting is](http://imgur.com/ZaJCZXj).

Comment: Many attempts to redesign the chair have been made but most fail to gain acceptance for the simple reason that there isn't really a problem with the existing fundamental design.

Comment: I'll edit my post with some resources. And yes @zzzzBov whether you like it or not, it is unhealthy for humans to sit upright. It's also unhealthy to go to the toilet the way we do, sitting up on the toilet. The fact that you find a picture or a monkey sitting on a branch doesn't mean it's healthy for humans to sit on a chair for 8 hours a day.

Comment: @MJB, These claims of "unhealthy" or "unnatural" remind me of https://twitter.com/laurendestefano/status/562715218112163841, and fail to include an important detail: they're only unhealthy in excess.

Comment: @zzzzBov I don't see connection with my post, since there is science to back up mine, but fair enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Chairs aren't badly designed (for the most part)

Of course there are chairs that put form before function and are uncomfortable, but chairs are **essentially designed to allow us to maintain an upright position (so we can work/socialize) while taking the load off our legs (so we can rest)**. In this sense, the fundamental design of a chair is successful.

If your issue is that they're bad if we sit in them for hours, that's **a usage issue, not a design issue.**

Comment: Right. They are (typically) designed for comfort, not to improve our health.

Comment: Great, an answer which actually helps! (unlike some of the comments on my original post) I looked at it wrongly, chairs aren't badly designed, they are simply not designed to sit on for several hours on a daily basis. Thanks!